# How can I execute a PL/SQL procedure for Oracle via JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a Java webapp with an Oracle DB, and I try to execute this statement at the end of a data migration script:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (ownname => 'MY_SCHEMA', tabname => 'MY_TABLE', estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size);
```

It works in sql*plus, but not via JDBC:

```
"Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EXEC (EXECUTE) is a SQL*Plus native command (just like SHUTDOWN, HELP, SET, etc.), and not a part of SQL itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of EXEC, you should put it between begin ... end, or use the { call } syntax.
Here is an example, in the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#i1014127

Answer (score 0):

```
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call MYPROCEDURE }");
cs.execute();
```